# Silverstripe 4 - Is the url "/resources" reserved?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have upgraded a site from 3.4 to 4.4, following the guide [here](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/upgrading/upgrading_project/) including step 8 for migrating to a public webroot.

I also have an existing URL and page type for displaying educational downloads called "/resources". After upgrade, this URL is changed to "/resources-2" and I'm picking that this is due to Silverstripe 4's own hard /resources directory.

Any options here? The CMS doesn't warn of anything. Do we need to come up with another URL for this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is configurable in the composer.json:

```
 "extra": {
        "resources-dir": "_resources"
    }
```

It was introduced in https://github.com/silverstripe/vendor-plugin/pull/26

Actually when you create a fresh SS4.4 project the resources folder should be named `_resources` by default.

Comment: Thanks. This sorted it. No SS4.4 didn't do this automatically and that's the only SS4 version I've used. I'm using "silverstripe/recipe-cms": "^4.4" if that matters. But thanks this sorted it anyway.